# Display a List<T> by using x:Bind?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the `x:Bind` stuff in UWP/xaml.
I'm learning more everyday and the app I'm curently writing is getting way easier to manage since I can implement the MVVM patterns now.

But there is one thing I encountered now...

I have a `List<T>` which I want to display in my UI. How can I bin this list while using `x:Bind`?

Or do I have to convert it into something else first?

Best Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use a `List<T>` for binding, but usually `ObservableCollection<T>` is preferable, because it also allows the UI to observe list changes, as opposed to `List<T>` that will not update after bound first. You can create an `ObservableCollection` from `List` using the constructor:

```
ObservableCollection<T> data = new ObservableCollection<T>( list );
```

In any case, you first have to create a property (but fields are also supported with `x:Bind`) in your view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<T> Data { get; } = new ObservableCollection<T>();
```

Remember that binding connects to the instance, so if you would set a new instance to `Data` property, it the binding would not update. For that to work you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your view mdoel and raise `PropertyChanged` event in the setter.

Now, to display the items in your UI you need a list control like `ListView` or `GridView` and bind it to your collection:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Data, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- your template -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomePropertyOfT}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You can find a thorough walk through data binding in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) as well.

Comment: I somehow managed to bin the list to my UI after I realized that I use the instance of my list... I'm a bit of a newbie regarding programming in c#. Totally overlooked that :D I guess I should be able to change the list into an ObservableCollection somehow. Since I create the list somewhere then I should be able to create an ObservableCollection instead.

Comment: Yes, either that or you could keep the List and ObservableCollection in sync (when something is added in the list, notify the ObservableCollection to do the same).

Comment: Usually changes in data are results of user actions, so you can most of the time react to those quite well :-)

Comment: I just exchange every menitioning of a List<T> with ObservableCollection<T> and the app is still working as before. So I guess that should be ok :D Just have to build some other stuff first before I can change any of the elements in the collection.

Comment: The only thing you have to keep in mind when using ObservableCollection is that any changes to the collection must be done on the UI thread, otherwise your app would crash. Otherwise there is not many differences between a List and ObservableCollection :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your desire is to have a collection which might change over time, and you want the UI to be notified of such modifications, you should not utilize `List<T>`!

Use instead `ObservableCollection<T>`, which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` which is the heart of the MVVM, allowing the ViewModel/View to communicate between each other. 
Such collection automatically handles the addiction/removal of elements automatically for you!

Anyway, here is a simple example, showing how you can use a *List* to communicate with your View.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    RandomList = new List<string>() {
        "random 1", "random 2", "random 3"
    };
}

List<string> RandomList { get; set; }
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind RandomList}" 
                PlaceholderText="List of Random things"/>
</Grid>
```

Here we defined a `{x:Bind }` to populate the ItemsSource's dependency property, which accepts a Collection.

- This Binding is defined with the default binding Mode, which is *OneTime* for compiled bindings. For instance, if you were to perform Bindings with `{Binding }` markup, the default mode is *OneWay*;
- Since you created a Collection with *List* rather than *ObservableCollection*, there would be no reason to specify any other mode than the default, since you haven't implement a mechanism for your *CLR* collection to actually notify the View of an update.